# He felt sick and threw up a lot because drinking too much one day before. - correct use of a participle phrase?

Tags: participle-clauses, participle-phrases

**Example 1**

> Because drinking too much one day before, he felt sick and threw up a lot.

**Example 2**

> He felt sick and threw up a lot because drinking too much one day before.

I know Example 1 is a correct use of the participle phrase.

However, can you put it at the end like Example 2?

Comment: Correction: Because **of** drinking too much the day before

Comment: You've got it the wrong way round! The *default* construction in English for most such utterances is *[statement] **because** [reason].* "Fronting" the ***because-*** clause is a (very slightly) "marked" form.

Comment: I hope the mods won't get too worked up about this, but chatgpt says: *In general, the construction "Because [reason], [statement]" is more common in formal writing, while the construction "[statement] because [reason]" is more common in informal writing and speech.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Because you quoted chatgpt, I'm in quite the lather. :)

Comment: @gotube: Well, given the primary *forte* of LLM AI's is predicting which word comes next, not only should chatGPT be reliable at things like knowing whether to include ***of*** after ***because*** - it should also be pretty good at noticing whether and where ***because-*** clauses normally come ***after*** the thing they purport to explain. Just my opinion, but I think normal spoken contexts are closer to the heart of language, so I'll always tend to promote that style to learners. Academic and literary usages aren't what most learners are hoping to become fluent in!

Answer (score 2):

Both are **incorrect**. Better would be *because he had drunk* or even *because **of** drinking*. And either of these can be reversed to put the cause after the effect.

Which ordering might be preferred depends on such considerations as which information—the nausea or the drinking—has already been under discussion and which is being introduced by this sentence. That consideration would lead one to place the topic being introduced at the end.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case 'example 2' makes much more sense. Stating the cause first and then the consequence makes it sound like vomiting is a foregone conclusion if you drink too much; whereas stating the consequence first makes it sound more noteworthy, which is true, because vomiting is an extreme consequence of drinking too much.

One more thing - it would be more idiomatic if you said he had drunk too much "***the** day before*" rather than 'one day' before.

> He felt sick and threw up a lot because **of** drinking too much **the** day before.

Comment: So, Example 2 is acceptable, am I right? Thank you for your revised example.

Comment: So can you put a participle phrase which follows a conjunction at the end?

Comment: @vincentlin Yes, it's quite common - as I said i my answer, I refer to this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

You can also say *He threw up **from** drinking too much the night before*.

> He was exhausted from traveling for two days without sleep.
>
> The children were dizzy from riding the spinning teacups at the carnival, and threw up their caramel apples, funnel cake, and cotton candy.
>
> He was itchy from being bitten by swarms of mosquitos.
>
> The astronaut's bones were weakened from spending months on the Space Station.